# Postfix mailq - Same 8 messages repeat 15 times

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I'm confused about this behavior by mailq. Usually, each message in the queue looks like the following:

```
6.5K             015C8069.4ED110A3.00005FF8          Nov 26 11:15
vmail            email@email.com
                 creditscorecenter@secure-financing-search.com
```

However, recently, it looks like the below example, with each message followed by a list of messages with "done" as the status? I'm extremely confused, as this exact pattern repeats over the entirety of the mailq as seen briefly below:

Any help/input would be awesome.

```
10.9K            014F0119.4ED29DCF.00004624          Nov 27 15:30
vmail
                 creditscorecenter@secure-financing-search.com
done             elizabeth.matthews@shoppping2save.com
done             deltaprime@shuffleuprights.com
done             solarpanels@solarpanelingnow.com
done             job.alerts.usa@solutionworking.com
done             hire@********
done             termfinder@termlifeprotect.com
done             age.quiz@theopenpathways2.com
                 bounce@truesavinglife.com
done             ultrasound.technician@ultratechjobs.com

6.5K             015C8069.4ED110A3.00005FF8          Nov 26 11:15
vmail
                 creditscorecenter@secure-financing-search.com    
done             elizabeth.matthews@shoppping2save.com
done             deltaprime@shuffleuprights.com
done             solarpanels@solarpanelingnow.com
done             job.alerts.usa@solutionworking.com
done             hire@********
done             termfinder@termlifeprotect.com
done             age.quiz@theopenpathways2.com
                 bounce@truesavinglife.com
done             ultrasound.technician@ultratechjobs.com
```

Comment: To make one thing clean. I have seen a lot of Postfix installation. But this output _does not_ look like an output from Postfix. Which version should that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some spammer has figured out how to relay through your machine to send spam! Since those have different message IDs I suspect the answer is they just sent it twice.

If you post the output of "postconf -n" someone (possibly me) can probably help you figure out how to stop that.

Also, to answer your question, I believe that those are messages with multiple recipients. Each "done" line is a copy of the email it sent.